# Find the max datediff between a list of dates in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am currently building a project where I report incidents, I am trying to figure out how to find the max datediff between the list of dates.
Here is what I've tried, I just can't get it to echo out my results.

```
<?php 
// connect to the database_ 
$connection = mysqli_connect('***','root','****','****'); 
$guid=$_SESSION['guid'];         
$guid=$_GET['guid']; 
//prepare query to select all 
$query="SELECT MIN(date_of_incident), MAX(date_of_incident) FROM incident  WHERE guid=$guid)"; 

//run query and store results 
$results=mysqli_query($connection,$query); 
$array = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){ 
  array[] = $row; 
  $max = $array[0];
  $min = $max;

  for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++){
    if ($array[$i] < $min)
      $min = $array[$i];
    if ($array[$i] < $max)
      $max = $array[$i];

    $day_count = (strtotime($max) - strtotime($min)) / (60*60*24);

    echo $day_count;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: too many brackets in query. should add error handling with `mysqli_error`.  also can simplify to something more like `SELECT datediff(MAX(date_of_incident), MIN(date_of_incident)) as max_difference FROM incident WHERE guid=$guid;`

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, when echoing the datediff results in the loop would i echo max_difference as the row?.

Comment: yep can just echo $row["max_difference"]

Comment: $query="SELECT datediff(MAX(date_of_incident),MIN(date_of_incident)) as max_difference FROM incident WHERE guid=$guid)"; 
 
 
//run query and store results 
$results=mysqli_query($connection,$query); 
 
 
 
While($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){ 


echo $row['max_difference'];


} 
 
?> I tried this but it wont seem to echo anything out for some reason

Comment: should add something like `if(!result)die(mysqli_error($connection));` between running the query and attempting to access the $results. otherwise looks good